# How to change the function being timed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to time all the different sorting algorithms to see which is fastest but every time I do that I need to rewrite the bottom half of the code again (under #####) except I have to change all the variable names (and instead of selectionsort(mylist) I do bubblesort(mylist) etc). I guess it's not the end of the world but I can't help but imagine it can be written much better. I know there are other options for timing it that may be better but I've been told I have to use perf_count.

```
def selectionsort(mylist):
    sortedlist=[]
    while len(mylist) > 0:
        lowest = mylist[0]
        for i in mylist:
            if i < lowest:
                lowest=i
        sortedlist.append(lowest)
        mylist.remove(lowest)
    return sortedlist

ivalues = [2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]
#####
sorttimelist = []
for i in range(1,11):
    mylist=[]
    for j in range(2**i):
        mylist.append(random.random())
    start_time=time.perf_counter()
    selectionsort(mylist)
    end_time=time.perf_counter()
    sorttime=end_time-start_time
    sorttimelist.append(sorttime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to go through different functions to use in your code. Since functions are essentially variables, you can assign one to `func` in the for loop, and call it like `func(my_list)`

```
#####
for func in [selectionsort, bubblesort]:
    for i in range(1,11):
        mylist=[]
        for j in range(2**i):
            mylist.append(random.random())
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        func(mylist)  # use func instead of selectionsort
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        sorttime = end_time - start_time
        sorttimelist.append(sorttime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over collection of functions you are going to benchmark. See example:

```
def selection_sort(my_list):
    pass

def bubble_sort(my_list):
    pass

functions = [selection_sort, bubble_sort]
for func in functions:
    func(list_to_sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a decorator, put `@timit` above your function.

```
import time

def timit(func):
    '''
    A Decorator that times how long it takes to return the function. Added time.sleep because some functions run under a seconds and would return 0 seconds.
    '''
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = float(time.time())
        time.sleep(1)
        test = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = float(time.time())
        print(f'Funtion {func.__name__} took {end-start-1} seconds to complete')
        return test
    return inner

@timit
def bubble_sort(array):
    for last_idx in range(1,len(array)):
        is_sorted = True
        for idx in range(len(array)-last_idx-1):
            if array[idx] > array[idx+1]:
                is_sorted = False
                swap(array, idx, idx+1)
        if is_sorted is True:
            break
    return array

@timit
def selection_sort(array):
    for first_idx in range(len(array)-1):
        smallest = array[first_idx]
        for idx in range(first_idx+1, len(array)):
            if array[idx] < smallest:
                smallest = array[idx]
                swap(array, idx, first_idx)
    return array
```